# How much personality should you put in the CV?

Tags: resume

People used to advice that emotion or personality is bad for your professional. However, many new studies say that you do something not because it's rational but because it's emotional (like the Inception movie). So if I put my personality on the CV, it will raise the emotion of the recruiter, therefore increase the chance of acceptance. Is this statement true? How much should you put on your CV?

For example, instead of saying: "I make choice by searching for information carefully and base on logical rather than emotional", which is long, I would rewrite it as: "Strategic, at least when playing chess. Or go. "

Comment: Are you sure you want to be posting your full name and contact information all over the internet?

Comment: I find no problem. Many people do that, like Bill Gates, Steve Jobs or Mark Zuckerberg :D

Comment: Well, I admit that is kind of self-esteem. So what if I change to "read many books"? I want to show that I can have knowledge in many field, and easy to learn new things. I'm asking here because I don't know how to show it properly. If you feel that I need to improve, can you show me where I should do that? "Who you are in one sentence", can you give me more detail? Thank you for being frank.

Comment: Hi Ooker.  It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking here.  We don't do resume critique and your question seems vague -- you want to show "personality", whatever you mean by that, but why is not clear and the question doesn't help.  "Strategic" doesn't seem like "personality" to me, for instance.  I see there are already some close votes, so I'm going to put this on hold so you can [edit] to clarify your question.

Comment: You writing is so poor that, whether you write with emotion or without, that I am not motivated to read it let alone spend extra time to make sense of it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: thanks for your comment. I just notice that it's just my writing style. I think the writing style indicates (partly) the owner personality. Should I edit it or ask a new question?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan: thanks for being frank. Have you read my full CV? The words in my question is my normal use and (of course) doesn't contain any emotion. Can you show me where should I improve this? Is the problem in language (grammar, vocabulary, etc) or other things? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I put my personality on the CV, it will raise the emotion of the
>   recruiter, therefore increase the chance of acceptance. Is this
>   statement true?

Part of it may be true. Part of it isn't.

Putting your "personality" on the CV may indeed raise the emotion of the recruiter.

That would depend on how good you are at writing, and how good you are at conveying your personality. If you are a very talented, creative type, you may be able to accomplish this. But if you are like most people, you will fail. Most people aren't good enough writers.

And raising the emotion of the recruiter will only increase your chance at acceptance, if the emotion is positive.

There are many, many other emotions that could be raised - anger, disgust, puzzlement, dismissal, etc. These emotions would almost certainly decrease your chance of acceptance.

In my opinion, there are only a few cases where creative, personality-driven CVs/resumes are helpful. If you are in a creative role (ad writer, artist, photographer, etc), and if you are an excellent writer - then and only then should this approach be attempted.

Otherwise, let your personality come out in your interviews, rather than in your CV writing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because I know that this base on how good my writing skill is, so I put my CV as an example. What do you think about my writing? Please be frank.

Comment: Do you know any place for asking this type of question? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I don't have any native speaker friend. Are there any forum to ask this?